# Подстановка в url get-параметров

Tags: html, javascript

Всем добрый день! Работаю над проектом, в котором при отключенных js навигация внутри раздела осуществляется через get-параметры. Если у юзера включены js - то все ссылки обрабатываются скриптом и происходит подгрузка аяксом. Что в итоге получается: адресная строка содержит только полный путь к разделу, а get-параметры не отображаются, т.к. ссылки перехватываются скриптом. И вот появилась необходимость в отображении этих параметров, например что бы можно было дать прямую ссылку на какой-то элемент из раздела.

Вопрос: как скриптом "приписывать" get-параметры в строку браузера? Спасибо, если не понятно - дам ссылку на разрабатываемый сайт.

**Добавлено**
Слышал краем уха, что проблему можно решить навешиванием якоря на манер

```
/some_path#var1=aaa
```

Однако при тесте параметры не подхватывались и грузилась начальная страница раздела, т.е. без учета параметров. Может накосячил с якорем?

**Добавлено**
Проблема решена, оформил ее как ответ на вопрос.

Comment: якорь, он же хеш ) обрабатывать придется ручками ) что то типа location.href.split('#') - получаем параметры и дальше уже выполняем необходимый запрос либо действия.

Comment: к стати похожий на ваш функционал реализован вконтакте, как это реализовано еще пока не разобрался, но смотрится прилично )

Comment: Как-то не обращал внимания... Надо будет посмотреть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрел на все предложенные варианты решения проблемы и понял, что мне не подходит ни один. И вот почему:
 1. window.location - перезагружает страницу
 2. window.history - не хочу ковырять историю, религия не позволяет ;)
 3. подключать сторонних скрипт ради мелочи - тоже не хочется.

Затем я полез смотреть иерархию объектов страницы и наткнулся на свойство

```
window.location.search
```

что дословно: "строка запроса или данные url после знака '?'"(Дунаев, самоучитель javascript). Нехитрыми манипуляциями меняем значение на нужное нам - и вуаля, страница не перезагружается, а строка вдреса в браузере отображает get-паметры!

Привожу обобщенный пример реализации:

```
<a href="?var1=123">Click Me</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("a").click(function(){
           var path = $(this).attr("href");
           //где-то здесь выполняются необходимые манипуляции, аякс-запросы и т.д.
           window.location.search = path;
           return false;
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Черт, все конечно хорошо, но все браузеры под линуксом перезагружают страницу при изменении window.location.search - видно я недосмотрел, когда тестировал в форточках... Решение проблемы так и не найдено :(

Comment: В общем навешивал якори и при заходе на странице проверял скриптом, есть якорь или нет. Если есть - подгружаем необходимый контент. Если js отключены - то грузится просто начальная страница раздела и всё.

Answer (score 2):

```
//var current_location = "<?=$_SERVER[QUERY_STRING].$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?>";
window.location = "thisfile.php?var1=bbb&var2=ccc";
```

Comment: Опачки, как все просто... Завтра утром попробую, спасибо :) Плюс Вам :)

Comment: можно еще узнавать текущий запрос, если надо какие-то параметры переносить без изменения

Comment: У меня проект на django - такие манипуляции не пройдут.

Comment: какие именно манипуляции? с узнаванием урла?

Comment: Извлечение текущих параметров:  

    <?=$_SERVER[QUERY_STRING].$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?>

Comment: В Django можно, если надо, пропихнуть в шаблон, используя [template context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).

Answer (score 2):

Я сегодня в соседнем вопросе уже рекомендовал [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js), но порекомендую и еще раз.

Если я правильно понял вопрос — это ровно то, что спрашивается.

Answer (score 0):

window.location замечательная функция, но в данной ситуации стоит учитывать одну неприятную особенность, при изменении адреса в адресной строке , автоматически перегружается страница. в связи с этим использование для аякс подгрузки весьма сомнительно. без перезагрузки можно использовать только хеш.

**Добавлено:**

можно использовать  pushState() или replaceState() объекта window.history и, как всегда, придется поработать для ie, но всё же лучше чем ничего )

Comment: Вот засада... Страница ни в коем случае не должна перегружаться!

Comment: как то так...